Error: Debug Failure after updating Angular from 16 to 17 during build or serve
I recently updated my Angular project from version 16 to 17. The update went smoothly, including the installation of node_modules. However, when I attempt to build or serve the project, I get the following error:
./src/app/pages/faculty/faculty-basic-details-update/faculty-basic-details-update.component.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js): Error: Debug Failure.
Versions in use :
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1703.11
@angular-devkit/build-angular      17.3.11
@angular-devkit/core               17.3.11
@angular-devkit/schematics         17.3.11
@angular/cdk                       17.3.10
@angular/cli                       17.3.11
@angular/material                  17.3.10
@angular/material-moment-adapter   17.3.10
@schematics/angular                17.3.11
rxjs                               7.8.1
typescript                         5.4.5
zone.js                            0.14.10
Node                               18.13.0

What I’ve tried so far:

Deleted node_modules and reinstalled them using npm install.
Ran ng update @angular/cli @angular/core to ensure compatibility.
Cleared the Angular cache using ng cache clean.
Checked for deprecated dependencies or breaking changes in package.json.

Despite these steps, the issue persists.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue during an upgrade to Angular 17? What are the possible causes of this Debug Failure error? Any advice or debugging tips would be greatly appreciated!
